# RxJS: invoke two async calls, return the first that passes a condition, or a special value of none of them does

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

Using RxJS, I want to invoke two different asynchronous operations, which may or may not return `null`. They may also take indefinite time to complete.

I want to achieve the following:

- If operation A returns *value 1*, then immediately return *value 1*
- If operation B returns *value 2*, then immediately return *value 2*
- If both operation A and B return `null`, then return `null`.

I suppose I can achieve the first two simply as follows:

```
const bothOperations = merge(callA(), callB());
const firstSuccess = bothOperations.first(res => res !== null);
return firstSuccess;
```

But how do I get the third possibility into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could do it like this (I'm assuming you're using RxJS 5.5):

```
merge(callA(), callB())
  .pipe(
    filter(v !== null),
    concat(of(null)),
    take(1),
  )
```

The `take(1)` operator makes sure only one value is passed and `concat(of(null))` appends `null` after both source Observables completed.

Just note that if both source Observables run indefinitely than this will never complete. You could add `timeout()` operator however.

Comment: Ah, that's clever. Thanks @martin!